# implicit load() in sencha touch store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a sencha touch store defined simply by a model and autoLoad=false. The model has only fields in its config, so I guess the data is stored within the memory, global to the application, am I right? (I'm new to sencha)

```
    Ext.define('App.store.DataSession', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        requires: ['App.model.DataSession'],

        config: { 
            model: 'App.model.DataSession',
            autoLoad: false
        } 

    });
```

My question is that I'm seeing a code that doesn't load the data from the store explicitly, even though the store has autoLoad false

```
    var storesession = Ext.getStore('DataSession');
    var datasession = storesession.getAt(0);                
    if(datasession.get('state') == "1"){
    ....
```

does the getStore() function load the data implicitly? what are the implications of not using load()?

Answer (score 0):

`getStore()` gets you a reference to the store.
If you want to load the data you have to e.g.:

```
var storesession = Ext.getStore('DataSession');
storesession.load({
    params: {
        id: 1 // some parameters
    },
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {  
        if(success) {
           var datasession = storesession.getAt(0);                
           if(datasession.get('state') == "1") {
            ....
        }
    }
});
```

Have a look here: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html

Comment: Thanks for the response ;) I don't know how the code without load() works, and why the code with callback doesn't return any data (in records or doing storesession.getAt(0)). Without load(), the data comes from memory instead of calling the proxy?